# Why Doesn't Direct Update happen on IBM MobileFirst Platform?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have developed a hybrid sample app on MobileFirst Platform 7.0. When I make any change in the .html file, direct update won't appear on the client mobile application (Android and iOS). Am I missing something? I have already deployed the `.wlapp` file on the server.

Comment: Have you changed the application version? In order for Direct Update to work, the application version must *not* change.

Comment: Also, just to be clear, you have already build and deployed the *updated* .wlapp file (with the new `.html`), right?

Comment: I haven't changed the app version.

No, I haven't updated the .wlapp.

Answer (score 1):

Direct Update will only work if the application connects to the server. Make sure that you are using the API method `WL.Client.connect()`, otherwise even if deploying an updated .wlapp to the server, the update will not be received in the application.

Comment: According to IBM Knowledge Center, no extra code is required for direct update implementation as it is a feature of MobileFirst Platform.

Comment: Well, you are wrong. Direct Update is a server-side feature and for it to work you must connect to the server. https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/advanced-client-side-development/using-direct-update-to-quickly-update-your-application/

Answer (score 0):

You say you haven't updated the `.wlapp`; you should. The Direct Update process works by fetching updated web content (HTML/CSS/JS/etc.) from inside the `.wlapp`. As Idan says, you also need to make sure your client is connecting to the server.

Comment: Ok. I would really appreciate if you could provide me any sample app of WL.Client.connect();

Comment: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/hello-world/connecting-to-the-mobilefirst-server/

Answer (score 0):

In order to begin communicating with MobileFirst Server you need to call WL.Client.connect() API method once the application start.
For Example in a main.js file :

```
 WL.Client.connect({
        onSuccess: function(){
            console.log("App is connected to the server...");
            // Call some methods ...
        },
        onFailure: function(){
            alert("unable to connect to the server...");
        }
    });
```

Make sure that you have built the .wlapp file with the correct configuration(Deployment target) and that's deployed successfully in the server.

Comment: OK. Thank you so much.